# Disable org-super-agenda on Emacs Start

Tags: org-super-agenda

I've enabled org-super-agenda to play with it and now Emacs displays my org-agenda when starting Emacs.

I don't find any way to disable that.

Any pointers?;)

Comment: Emacs restores settings from the .emacs and other initialization files and from the .emacs.desktop. The easiest way would be to delete/rename these files. Another approach: search for `-agenda` in .emacs and all files in .emacs.d directory to find out which file you need to edit.

Comment: What exactly did you to enable it in the first place? If the agenda is displayed automatically when you start Emacs, then look in your init file for a call to `org-agenda` or similar. You need to provide more information.

Comment: I don't use `org-super-agenda`. But I guess from my inspection of the [source code](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda/blob/master/org-super-agenda.el) that you just have to switch off `org-super-agenda-mode` via `M-x customize-option` `org-super-agenda-mode`. It is a [globally defined minor mode](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda/blob/f4f528985397c833c870967884b013cf91a1da4a/org-super-agenda.el#L340).